# chain operations after channelInactive called

Tags: java, netty

I have some clean-up code in channelInactive:

```
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    clean-up code
    super.channelInactive(ctx);
}
```

Sometimes, I need disconnect channel actively:

```
ChannelFuture f = channel.disconnect();
f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
     public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
         // the problem is the channelInactive might not be called yet
         // how can I make sure channelInactive has been called?
         do something but the clean-up code in channelInactive MUST be called
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty unable to do this. If channel.disconnect called not in netty's event loop, it will fire those events like channelInactive asynchronously, so there is no order between disconnect and it's relatived events will be fire.

code in `AbstractChannelHandlerContext`:

```
static void invokeChannelInactive(final AbstractChannelHandlerContext next) {
    EventExecutor executor = next.executor();
    if (executor.inEventLoop()) {
        next.invokeChannelInactive();
    } else {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                next.invokeChannelInactive();
            }
        });
    }
}
```